# Codeigniter/PHP Outer JOIN Syntax on Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, outer-join

I am trying to perform an outer JOIN  3 tables based on the "site_id" column in each table.  I'm using Codeigniter/Active Record.

The user enters a site number via a form and once the number is submitted it should call the model that executes something like this:

```
$site_id = $this->input->post('site_id');

$this
->db
->select('*')
->where('site_id', $site_id)
->from('sites')
->join('leader', 'sites.site_id = leader.site_id', 'outer')
->join('state', 'sites.site_id = state.site_id', 'outer');

$q = $this->db->get();
```

However I get the following error message:

"Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN `leader` ON `sites`.`site_id` = `leader`.`site_id` OUTE' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`sites`) OUTER JOIN `leader` ON `sites`.`site_id` = `leader`.`site_id` OUTER JOIN `state` ON `sites`.`site_id` = `state`.`site_id` WHERE `site_id` = '63'

Filename: /home2/cdowney/public_html/mclinbase.com/models/viewsite_model.php

Line Number: 33"

I believe(hope) this is just a small syntax error that I'm missing or a misuse of the outer join but I have not been able to figure it out.

Any guidance?

Comment: Your where clause is ambiguous, append the table name with the column name `sites.site_id = '63'`

Comment: You also don't have full joins in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('sites.site_id', $site_id);
$this->db->from('sites');
$this->db->join('leader', 'sites.site_id = leader.site_id', 'outer');
$this->db->join('state', 'sites.site_id = state.site_id', 'outer')

$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Remember, you are not only answering this question for one person, you are also answering all future questions/OPs where this page is used as a duplicate closure link.

Answer (score 0):

Simply union select the left and right join to get the same result as outer join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Maybe this will help.